# How to renew Letsencrypt on Google Compute Engine SSH Terminal

Tags: terminal, certbot

I need to know the exact reason for the "insecure" issues my certificate is having. I'm not really this tech savvy so I'm not sure what I need to check. This is the message I get when I try to re-run the scripts:

```
/certbot-auto certonly --webroot -w /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/ -d mwosa.com -d www.mwosa.com
Requesting to rerun ./certbot-auto with root privileges...
./certbot-auto has insecure permissions!
To learn how to fix them, visit https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certbot-auto-deployment-best-practices/91979/
Upgrading certbot-auto 0.39.0 to 1.2.0...
Replacing certbot-auto...
Creating virtual environment...
Installing Python packages...
Installation succeeded.
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Renewing an existing certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for mwosa.com
http-01 challenge for www.mwosa.com
Using the webroot path /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs for all unmatched domains.
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a message of permissions, it’s probably that the letsencrypt folder needs write protection, the directory path containing certbot-auto (which includes every directory accessed in the absolute path to certbot-auto) doesn’t allow writing for low privileged users. You can follow the instructions to fix this issue in [Certbot-auto deployment best practices](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certbot-auto-deployment-best-practices/91979).

If you have to write access to /opt, then anyone could do:

```
mv /opt/letsencrypt /opt/somethingelse
mkdir /opt/letsencrypt
echo 'echo owned >> /root/owned' > /opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto
chmod -R a+x /opt/letsencrypt
```

and it would fire the next time the root cronjob runs letsencrypt-auto with root privileges.